# Python3. I get an error when I deepcopy the instance of the class that has cv2.VideoCapture in __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, opencv

Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

class Video:

def __init__(self, path):

    self.name = path.split('/')[-1]
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
```

When I create an instance of Video class and try to deep copy it I get this error.

```
video = Video('video.mp4')
print(video)
print(deepcopy(video))
```

ERROR:

> <**main**.Video object at 0x103496630>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 28, in 
>       print(deepcopy(video))
>     File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyvideoproc-x3IHrdzn/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
>       y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
>     File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyvideoproc-x3IHrdzn/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
>       state = deepcopy(state, memo)
>     File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyvideoproc-x3IHrdzn/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
>       y = copier(x, memo)
>     File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyvideoproc-x3IHrdzn/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
>       y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
>     File "/Users/tigranfahradyan/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyvideoproc-x3IHrdzn/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
>       rv = reductor(4)
>   TypeError: can't pickle cv2.VideoCapture objects

But when I remove 'cv2.VideoCapture(path)', everything works fine.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

class Video:

    def __init__(self, path):

        self.name = path.split('/')[-1]
```

Output:

> <**main**.Video object at 0x10d0f7c18>
>   <**main**.Video object at 0x119693eb8>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of figured out how to solve this, but I am sure this is not the best way. For some reasons it gives an error when you try to deepcopy the instance of the class that has a field set to 'cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)'.

But you can have local variable like this.

```
import cv2

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)

        """This will probably give an error for you 
           if you try to deepcopy the instance of this class"""
        # self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
```